# Convert video to exe in C# Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, video, exe

I have a requirement to convert a Video into a .exe file using C# Winforms. This is needed to ensure there is no illicit redistribution of my video file.

I am having a hard time implementing this. Below is my findings so far using Google.

**Approach 1: Add reference to WMP.dll and insert the Windows Media Player control onto the Form.**  
This control expects URL to bind a video to the url, meaning I need to have the Video file added physically in the project folder. Doing this defies the purpose of the project as my video file will be spit out after the build process in the bin/debug or /bin/release folder.

I understand I can embed the video file in the Resource file. However the Windows Media Player control cannot read from byte array or stream of the Resource file. There is no way to assign a resource file directly to Windows Media Player control.

I even came across a suggestion of writing the byte array of resource file into a physical file in the User's temp folder. However this may be risky as once a user identifies about this, the illicit redistribution may happen.

**Approach 2: Adding reference to Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback**
Using this, it throws "VFW_E_UNSUPPORTED_STREAM" exception. My video is in .mp4 format. Some forums suggest if I install supporting codecs this exception should be taken care of. However I cannot do this as I cannot expect my users to install codecs on their system only to view a video. (Dot net framework is presumed to be present on every user's machine)

Can anyone help me out here please? Please let me know if you need any extra information and I shall be more than happy to oblige.

Here is a reference link. This is exactly what I need to implement [http://www.videotoexe.com](http://www.videotoexe.com/)

Thanks in advance to all.

Comment: i suppose you should embed all dependencies  to your .exe file. If this is  the purpose you might look at ffmpeg library. İt might solve the problem. Also note that, embedding codecs and required libraries into an executable file may cause  too large binary size than you expect

Comment: 1. If you place your video in Resources, why do you think, that I can't unpack your .exe file (with **DotNetResourcesExtract** or similar) and simply copy your file? 2. Do you protect it from taking on phone camera, or any display capture software? 3. If this video is SO MUCH secret, maybe you just do not distibute it to public? Show it behind closed doors, or even don't show it at all?

Comment: @vasily.sib it can very unpack the resource wihin exe, however this unpacked file will be a physical file as the media control expects a URL to a video. Hence it defies the purpose. I hope i interpreted your suggestion correctly.

Comment: @arnes I think you did make a bit of sense to me. Just a small clarification. Do you mean that I can include ffmpeg codec within my exe and when the user execute the file, this codec will install silently and play the video?

Comment: It is not actually a suggestion:\ What I mean is - you are inventing a very strange bicycle. Is there any really strong reason for this?

Comment: Silently install anything in user system is bad. Nobody like this.

Comment: @vasily.sib Further to my comment above. I think I got you wrong. Yes you are right. You can extract using DotNetResourcesExtract. The video is not a big secret. It is a copyright issue. The video is meant to be seen by users. However to restrict piracy our client have decided to distribute using a EXE.

Comment: I get your point. Silently installing is bad. And even I dont suppor this thought. I was rephrasing my understanding of what @arnes suggested of embedding the codec within the exe itself.

Comment: @HarshitGandhi if this is only a copyright issue, maybe you just hire a lawyer and add a copyright warning in the begining of video? More then that, are you sure, that your users wouldn't find this approach is suspicious? If I download a **video**, I expect this will by an *.avi, or *.mp4, or any other video file, but not an **executable**. I will delete it as soon as I can.

Comment: @vasily.sib I had exactly the same debate with my client. Even I would delete the exe file when expecting a video. But somehow client is adamant on delivery a exe file. :(

Comment: @vasily.sib check this out. [videotoexe converter](http://www.videotoexe.com) this is exactly what i need to implement.

Comment: If it is exactly what you need, purchase the product.

Comment: @HarshitGandhi yes, ffmpeg provides encoder decoder and playing mechanism in library, i am not sure how to do but i suppose you can achieve by linking it statically to your exe. maybe some of experienced user about ffmpeg could help you

Comment: @HarshitGandhi if you really need this, here: supported "by default" formats list https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/316992/file-types-supported-by-windows-media-player. Use 2nd approach and reencode video in well-known-format

Comment: @nabuchodonossor i need to add more funtionality in it too. So I cant purchase it. But the core feature of Video to Exe what I need exactly like that link.

Comment: @arnes thanks. I ll spend some time playing around with ffmpeg.

Comment: @vasily.sib Thanks for the link. It shows .mp4 support for WMP 12, however it still asks for codecs.

Comment: @HarshitGandhi: Ok, I understand, wasn´t aware of the additional features.

Answer (score 0):

WMP can open media files by an URL. Implement a local web server in your winforms app, embed the video as a resource (preferably somehow encrypted), read the embedded resource as stream, (decrypt on demand) and let WMP consume the stream via a local URL.

Answer (score 0):

So I am finally using VLC.DotNet instead of WMP. It supports stream playing as well as .srt for subtitles.

Marking this question closed for now.

Thanks everyone for all your thoughts and suggestion.